# SCP a file between two servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp

I have a Digital Ocean droplet (SERVER A) that uses an SSH key and password for my root account. I created an additional user and added it to a new SFTPUsers group by following this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-restrict-a-user-to-a-specific-directory

I also have another server on a shared host (not on Digital Ocean) that has nightly backup files. (SERVER B)

I would like to securely copy these nightly backups each night from SERVER B to a directory on my DO server (SERVER A) that my backup user has access to, and would like to do it with a script so that it doesn't ask for a password so it can just run. I'm really confused about where to go from here. I find the more I research, the more confused I get. I generate a public/private key on SERVER B and then copy the public key to server A? Then what happens?

Where do I go from here as far as being able to SCP a file from my one server to the digital ocean server? I'd like to do this using my new user I created. Would really welcome any help / pointers in the right direction. I tried doing reading on SSH / public/private keys but still don't feel like I'm making progress :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to create a different SSH key for this user? I would do that on the DO server? I can't even log in as this new user because it says access denied (public key) when I try to login. I can log in as root, however, when I use that key.

You can of course use the same key for everything. However, it would be better use different keys for different users. So I'd recommend generating a key for a non-`root`-user. (And maybe not entering a passphrase, or else you'll have to understand `ssh-agent` (see below).) You would generate the key on the DO server and then append the public key... see next step.

> How can I ensure the droplet will allow access from this other server? I read that you can copy the public key created on the DO server to the shared server's .ssh dir and then append it to authorized_keys. Is that correct?

You don't have to copy it to the `~/.ssh` directory. You just have to append it to `authorized_keys` in the `~/.ssh` directory.

> Even if the key is copied over, it would still have a password as well that I would need to type in, no? Where does that get saved to? An environment variable?

Only if you entered a passphrase when you generated your key. You can store passphrases by using `ssh-agent`. Running `ssh-agent` will run a background process that takes care of filling in the passphrase when you `ssh` (or `scp` etc.) into a different server, but only for keys that you have `ssh-add`ed. It will also output a few lines likes this:

```
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-mjHm7nFyhJSh/agent.21838; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=21839; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 21839;
```

These are shell commands. If you paste them into your shell, you will be able to make use of `ssh-agent` in that shell. You can also do `eval $(ssh-agent)` to automatically evaluate `ssh-agent`'s output by the shell. Then you do `ssh-add` (for the default `.ssh/id_rsa` key, or `ssh-add path/to/key` and enter the passphrase once. In that terminal you will now be able to `ssh` into other servers without entering the passphrase, even if you generated your key with a passphrase.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. If I want to generate a key for a non-root user, I just have to log in as that user on the box, and generate a key? Now if I generate the key on the DO BOX (A), remember my goal is to copy files from B to A using the backup user I created on Server A. To do that, do I copy the public key for my user from server A onto Server B and append it to authorized_keys ? After that, would my SCP command work? Basically Server B needs the public key, and server A needs the private key, correct?

Comment: Correct. BTW, the public key is entirely made from normal printable characters, so you can just copy and paste it into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the other server.

Comment: Do I want to give this user a home directory? Is it a normal user? I want to restrict them so even if someone compromised server B, they couldn't do much damage

Comment: Yeah, normal user. You couldn't put anything in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` if there were no home directory. You can log in from A to B, but not from B to A, so nothing to worry about.

Comment: but to confirm, copying A's public key over to B allows me to run SCP from B and copy a file to A?

Comment: No, you will run `scp` from A. Think `scp B:/path/to/remote/source/file /path/to/local/destination/file`